# Deploying Java Spring Rest Service To Tomcat 6.0.20

Tags: java, spring, deployment, web.xml, spring-boot

I'm fairly new with Spring Framework and struggling to get this simple example to work on a Tomcat 6 instance.  The example is here http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ .

It works fine when i run it within Eclipse but when i convert it to a WAR file and deploy, the directory in Tomcat is created but the service/tomcat responds with a 404.

I suspect i need to create a web.xml file (not sure the annotated way will work with tomcat 6 because it supports only servlet 2.5) but not sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say that you converted it to a WAR file, did you follow this guide, which explains how to convert a Spring Boot application to a WAR? http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: Afair `Spring Boot` does not support older servlet 2.5 container e.g. Tomcat6. There are however attempts to fix this: https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy

Comment: @Andreas I believe your comment actually answers the question

Comment: I think this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974475/does-spring-boot-support-servlet-2-5-auto-configuration